# Can't restore cookies from a previous CasperJS session

Tags: javascript, cookies, phantomjs, casperjs

I tried to use command or used phantom to read the file, but it didn't work.

```
var data = fs.read(path) 
phantom.cookies = JSON.parse(data)    
system.stdout.writeLine('============Get the cookie============');
```

```
casperjs.bat --cookies-file=cookie.txt --web-security=false a.js
```

I login into a website using this command, it generates a cookie file and then exit. When I restart this script and visit the website, I still need to login in.

I need it keep login status and click some user button and get the information.

How can I deal with it?

Comment: If you're using a cookies file, then you don't need to read and write cookies in your script.